# What does "Not without pride" mean in this context?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Context: "As this story is about my experiences as an ordinary prisoner, it is important that I mention, **not without pride**, that I was not employed as a psychiatrist in camp, or even as a doctor, except for the last few weeks."

Does this mean he felt pride, he felt shameful, or something else? 
Thanks!

Comment: Double negatives in English traditionally equal positives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth did you flag it? I can't actually tell (I have, but if that text is automatic it doesn't add it again when I flag it) ...

Comment: It means that the author doesn’t dislike multiple negatives.    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is an example of [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes): saying something by denying the opposite. It means that he feels proud but is pretending that he does not want to boast.

Answer (score -1):

*Litotes* is when an affirmative is expressed by the negative of the contrary (OED). The OP litotes - *not without pride* - suggests that the speaker takes pride in the fact that he was not employed as a psychiatrist in camp, or even as a doctor, except for the last few weeks.

The passage also illustrates the problem of saying what you mean by expressing it as a double negative: The meaning is, usually, less clear.

Litotes often implies a subtext which requires context to be understood. Used well, it can be used effectively for a variety of purposes.  For example:

to tease:

> "...you didn't look completely out of place"

to reproach;

> "...the fact you were drunk didn't make you useless"

to minimise impact;

> "...don't worry, it wasn't the worst thing in the world"

to sound modest;

> "...I'm not unfamiliar with Beethoven's music"

to highlight how preconceived notions may, in fact, be wrong;

> "...this isn't a bad road"

But it is easy to use litotes clumsily and the result can make a speaker sound pompous, ridiculous and falsely modest.